# Error when updating from 3.1.11 to 3.1.15

Tags: craft3, updates

After I run an update, I get this error:  '⚠' is not a numeric value.

I've tried to run the updates multiple times with the same result. I was also able to update plugins with no issues.

```
yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: '⚠' is not a numeric value. in /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/Formatter.php:1727
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/Formatter.php(1120): yii\i18n\Formatter->normalizeNumericValue('\xE2\x9A\xA0')
#1 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/2a/2a36518ebcb9289a64362cd02a4e956e899306f594506209175012a354aa7f4a.php(256): yii\i18n\Formatter->asDecimal('\xE2\x9A\xA0')
#2 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(189): __TwigTemplate_309d4a2d35cb1be418317a1eb31479912dc2e29bd3ce7de12b3a82e142f925b1->block_body(Array, Array)
#3 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/8f/8f387ea7239e223174d45ae0db27e78376dd6e6173ff6af3424e619d468194a3.php(60): Twig_Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#4 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_528fb73bf994ffb8674e86b1402d5674f1759e4d18c4ec17f78c8f7e25afea1a->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#5 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#6 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#7 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#8 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/b8/b81a0968284caf5539abd48dd170f68a8f9af859c2dd07891efa76851f233b2f.php(40): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#9 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_3eb157a482306a2333e424d0364b9e19e8fac10078663d1717682b5b86788461->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#12 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#13 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/2a/2a36518ebcb9289a64362cd02a4e956e899306f594506209175012a354aa7f4a.php(95): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#14 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_309d4a2d35cb1be418317a1eb31479912dc2e29bd3ce7de12b3a82e142f925b1->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#15 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#16 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#17 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#18 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/0f/0f685de995db652b5d0a838725a18baf3c14d5372176507e7c9ba8f9e729361c.php(32): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#19 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(386): __TwigTemplate_866c826e7a1cf0e14d098c3c82972cffd04d519091073cfa11c0b12e056a263c->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#20 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(49): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#21 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(363): craft\web\twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#22 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Template.php(31): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#23 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(371): craft\web\twig\Template->display(Array)
#24 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(289): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#25 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(337): Twig_Environment->render('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#26 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(384): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#27 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(161): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#28 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php(92): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('utilities/_inde...', Array)
#29 [internal function]: craft\controllers\UtilitiesController->actionShowUtility('updates')
#30 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#32 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(109): yii\base\Controller->runAction('show-utility', Array)
#33 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('show-utility', Array)
#34 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(297): yii\base\Module->runAction('utilities/show-...', Array)
#35 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('utilities/show-...', Array)
#36 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(286): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#37 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#38 /Users/mariovasquez/Documents/CODE/craft-3/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#39 {main}
```

Comment: Can you edit the original question to share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird.  If you want to send a 3.1.11 database backup and composer.json file over to support@craftcms.com, we can try to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that I fixed in [Webperf 1.0.4](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-webperf/releases/tag/1.0.4)

I was using the badge count to display an emoji, and then a change in Craft 3.1.15 caused them to enforce that the badge count could be numeric only.

Anyway, just update to the latest [Webperf](https://nystudio107.com/plugins/webperf) and you'll be all set.